# Разница функции Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

В чем разница между `$request->get('name')` и `$request['name']`?

Comment: разница в том, что встроенные функции проверяют входные данные. Не изобретайте колесо. И юзайте `->input()`

Comment: @n.osennij какое колесо?) Не вижу ничего плохого в варианте `$request['name']` или `$request->name`. При таком варианте ничего не мешает тоже проверять данные (работает через `__get`). Но насколько видно по исходникам в обеих случаях нет никакой проверки, а просто доступ к данным. Если говорить о разнице input и динамических свойств, то в input идет использование хелпера `data_get` что пользволяет использовать точечную нотацию, в input данные ищутся сначала в request, потом в query, а в динамических свойствах как я писал в ответе: сначала в request потом в параметрах маршрута.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько вижу в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input) не упоминается про `->get(...)`, но указывается `->input(...)`

Вот что пишут в [исходниках](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L321) laravel:

> This method belongs to Symfony HttpFoundation and is not usually
>   needed when using Laravel.

И еще:

> Instead, you may use the "input" method.

В документации в разделе **Retrieving Input Via Dynamic Properties** про второй способ пишут:

> You may also access user input using dynamic properties on the
>   `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance. When using dynamic properties,
>   Laravel will first look for the parameter’s value in the request
>   payload. If it is not present, Laravel will search for the field in
>   the route parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$request->get() //Возвращает все данные только из GET запроса
$request->post() //Возвращает данные только из POST запроса
$request['data'] //Доступ ко всем данным по ключу
```